# How to use \\?PnP?\Notification to get the card status change when calling SCardGetStatusChange API using a card reader

Tags: visual-c++, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I want to detect card insert/remove event in a card reader without having to poll using VC++.

When I use `\\?PnP?\Notification` in `SCardGetStatusChange` API. I get the result as
0x80100009 - the specified reader name is not recognised and the `EventState` always remains 0.

Also can someone point to some samples on how I can listen to `\\?PnP?\Notification` event and proceed accordingly.

I want to detect card insert/remove event in a card reader without having to poll using VC++.